# Pass DataType of the Class

Tags: json, kotlin, gson, deserialization

I have the following data class, which stores two values, JSON and dataType:

```
data class DataTypeItem(
    var json     : String = "",
    var dataType : Class<*> ?= null
)
```

I have the list defined in the following way:

```
val dataTypeList = mutableMapOf<String, DataTypeItem>()

dataTypeList.put( "item_1", DataTypeItem( json1, MyDataType::class.java ) )
dataTypeList.put( "item_2", DataTypeItem( json1, List<MyDataType>::class.java ) )
```

Please note that in one case I'm using the MyDataType as the DataType and in the other List < MyDataType >.

Now I would like to loop through each of the dataTypeList items and parse JSON for the given data type into it's model:

```
fun init()
{
    dataTypeList.forEach {
        dataTypeItem ->
            val model = Gson().fromJson( dataTypeItem.value.json, dataTypeItem.value.dataType::class.java )
    }
}
```

I'm using the following model:

```
data class dataTypeItem(
    @SerializedName("sqlId")
    val sqlId: String,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String
)
```

But I keep getting an Runtime exception:

```
Attempted to deserialize a java.lang.Class. Forgot to register a type adapter?
```

In addition, in case it's a list, I need to call toList() on Gson().fromJSON(..):

```
fun init()
{
    dataTypeList.forEach {
        dataTypeItem ->
            val model;

            if( dataTypeItem.value.dataType::class.java is Array )
                model = Gson().fromJson( dataTypeItem.value.json, dataTypeItem.value.dataType::class.java ).toList()
            else
                model = Gson().fromJson( dataTypeItem.value.json, dataTypeItem.value.dataType::class.java )
    }
}
```

How can I pass the dataType dynamically and distinguish if it's a List/Array or straight up class? In addition, whenever I try to call toList(), I get an error that it's undefined.

**If I specify the class directly, then it's working fine**

```
 var model = Gson().fromJson( json, DataTypeItem::class.java )
```

or

```
 var model = Gson().fromJson( json, Array<DataTypeItem>::class.java )
```

**but I need to be able to specify it dynamically as an argument**

Comment: what is the class that you are trying to deserialize when you get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
val dataTypeMap = mapOf(                                                                                                                              
    "item_1" to MyDataTypeItem("""{"sqlId" : "1",  "name" : "a"}""", MyDataType::class.java),                                                           
    "item_2" to MyDataTypeItem("""[{"sqlId" : "1",  "name" : "a"}, {"sqlId" : "2",  "name" : "b"}]""", Array<MyDataType>::class.java)                  
)                                                                                                                                                     

val result = dataTypeMap.map{ Gson().fromJson(it.value.json, it.value.dataType) }
```

I renamed `DataTypeItem` to `MyDataTypeItem` and `dataTypeItem` to `MyDataType`.

Why you need to call toList()? If it is really necessary you can do the following instead:

```
val result = dataTypeMap.map {                                                                                           
    if (it.value.dataType?.isArray == true) Gson().fromJson<Array<*>>(it.value.json, it.value.dataType).toList()        
    else Gson().fromJson(it.value.json, it.value.dataType)                                                              
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did a stupid mistake and used the variable like this dataTypeItem.value.dataType::class.java instead of dataTypeItem.value.dataType. One problem I'm still facing is that it doesn't seem to detect that it's an array, I tried when(it.value.dataType) but it still always goes to else condition. Any hints please? Thanks!

Comment: No problem ;). You are right, the previous code was wrong, but I believe it is working now.